# Rails naming convention issue with single letters

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to create a table named :

```
nomenclature_b_c_consistency_control
```

rails model generator do it well and create a class :
`NomenclatureBCConsistencyControl` in a model file `models/nomenclature_b_c_consistency_control.rb`

Which is what I except.
But, rails autoloading silently fail to load this model.

When I try to access it, (eg :`NomenclatureBCConsistencyControl.first`) I got the following error `NameError: uninitialized constant NomenclatureBCConsistencyControl`

However, if a rename it to something like that (removing single letters) : `NomenclatureConsistencyControl`
in a file `models/nomenclature_consistency_control.rb`

The model is well autoloaded.

Why the hell, rails generator create the file and model without issues and rails autoloader can't load it ?

There is a workaround ?

Comment: A workaround which seems to work is to name my table nomenclature_bc_consistency_control

Comment: When you say rails autoloading silently fail to load this model, did you get any error?

Comment: No, rails load without errors, just the model is not in global constants. (I get error when trying to access the model : NameError: uninitialized constant NomenclatureBCConsistencyControl)

Comment: Can you add your model and also the full error in the question please?

Comment: After investigating, this is a rails strange behavior. It's reported here : https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9326